# Find all radio groups which haven't been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic quiz/survey type application I'm working on, and I'd like to give the user a prompt before they submit if they haven't answered all the questions. All the questions are multiple choice using radio buttons:

```
<div class="question">
    Q1: What is the second letter of the alphabet?
    <div class="choices">
        <input type="radio" name="question_1" value="1" /> A
        <input type="radio" name="question_1" value="2" /> B
        <input type="radio" name="question_1" value="3" /> C
    </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
    Q2: Which out of these is a berry?
    <div class="choices">
        <input type="radio" name="question_2" value="1" /> Apples
        <input type="radio" name="question_2" value="2" /> Bananas
        <input type="radio" name="question_2" value="3" /> Carrots
    </div>
</div>
<div class="question"> ...etc
```

How do you find which groups haven't got an option ticked? Or at least, if there are any which haven't been answered?

jQuery is ok, and even preferred.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out:

```
$('div.question:not(:has(:radio:checked))')
```

Comment: Saved my day :)

Comment: Not exactly intuitive, especially because I need to have each radio group with the same wrapper class, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Saved my day too THANK YOU, sir!