# Radio Button Check w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

What would be the best way to loop through all radio buttons on my page and alert the user if one of them is unchecked for a particular question?

Note: there are multiple questions on one page.

```
<li>
  <fieldset>
  <h3>What music do you listen to?</h3>  

        <ul class="answerList">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="choice_22" name="answer8" value="1" class=""/>
                <label for="choice_22" class="">Heavy Metal  </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="choice_23" name="answer8" value="2" class=""/>
                <label for="choice_23" class="">Pop music</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="choice_24" name="answer8" value="3" class=""/>
                <label for="choice_24" class="">Oh, a mix of stuff </label>
            </li>
         </ul>
       </fieldset>   
      </li>
```

Comment: These should be checkboxes, not radio buttons.  Radio buttons assert there are N number of choices, but only one can be selected from the group.  Checkboxes say that there are N choices, any combination of which are viable selections, like your answer list.

Comment: their meant to be radio's, only one answer can be selected

Comment: there are multiple questions on one page, the above is just an example of one question. what i'm trying to do is make sure on submit of the form that none of the questions are left unanswered

Comment: That's clearer.  However, when you're talking about music, you gotta expect people to listen to more than one genre (insert smiley face here)...

Answer (score 12):

```
if (undefined === $("input[name='answer8']:checked").val()) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Btw in jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (in 1.2 they were deprecated)

Comment: I updated the syntax to reflect that latest API (simply remove the "@" character and you are good to go). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

Try these:

[Find all radio groups which haven't been selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249214/find-all-radio-groups-which-havent-been-selected)
[Validation of radio button group using jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277589/validation-of-radio-button-group-using-jquery-validation-plugin)