# jquery: how to check if all radio buttons in a div are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html looks like this

```
<div id="div1">
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="v1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="v2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="v3" />

  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="v1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="v2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="v3" />

  <input type="radio" name="r3" value="v1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r3" value="v2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r3" value="v3" />
</div>
```

radio buttons are dynamically generated on my html so in that div i don't know how many radio buttons i have.

i want to make sure that the user will select a value for each one of them before he submits the form, how can i check that all radio buttons inside my div has a value checked?

Thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Restructure your HTML slightly** - wrap each radio group in (say) a div. Then you can just do something like this to validate the form when the user submits it:

```
if ($('div:not(:has(:radio:checked))').length) {
    alert("At least one group is blank");
}
```

Of course this can be tweaked in various ways to suit your HTML. The idea was from [Find all radio groups which haven't been selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249214/find-all-radio-groups-which-havent-been-selected)

Answer (score 33):

```
$(":radio").change(function() {
    var names = {};
    $(':radio').each(function() {
        names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });
    var count = 0;
    $.each(names, function() { 
        count++;
    });
    if ($(':radio:checked').length === count) {
        alert("all answered");
    }
}).change();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yFaAj/15/

Comment: Wow __so__ much better than my answer. +1

Comment: The title doesn't imply it, but I'm pretty sure he would want to ensure that one from each set is checked. Since they're radios, you really can't select more than one from a group.

Comment: but the problem is that i don't know how many radio buttons group like r1 ... r2 ... rN i have in my html it's dynamically generated

Comment: @Bennett McElwee - the solution would be to trigger `.change` onload. I'll edit.

Comment: @karim79 The code is getting more and more complex. I'd suggest using events is not the best approach. See my answers for some simpler ideas... :)

Comment: @Bennett McElwee - Not complex, just a few lines of code. Besides, how's he going to make use of it outside of events?

Comment: @karim79 I mean that you might as well wait till the user submits the form before validating, rather than doing it every time they click a radio button.

Comment: You call `.change()` at the end of the chain. Won't that validate the *entire* form once for *every* radio button? Perhaps the validation function needs to be factored out.

Comment: @Bennett McElwee - That is a sound point, no argument there, unless OP needs to provide immediate feedback to the user (e.g. something turns green when all selections have been made).

Comment: you can skip the whole `count` section if you just check `$(':radio:checked').length === Object.keys(names).length`

Answer (score 8):

**Solution here** [http://jsfiddle.net/QxdnZ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/QxdnZ/)

```
    var checked = $("#div1 :radio:checked");
    var groups = [];
    $("#div1 :radio").each(function() {
        if (groups.indexOf(this.name) < 0) {
            groups.push(this.name);
        }
    });
    if (groups.length == checked.length) {
        alert('all are checked!');
    }
    else {
        var total = groups.length - checked.length;
        var a = total>1?' groups are ':' group is ';

        alert(total + a + 'not selected');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something along these lines? http://jsfiddle.net/gXsZp/3/

```
<div id="div1">
   Q1
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="v1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="v2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="v3" />
  <br/>Q2

  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="v1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="v2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="v3" />
    <br/>Q3  

  <input type="radio" name="r3" value="v1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r3" value="v2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r3" value="v3" />
</div>
<br/>
<input id="btn" type="submit" text="submit"/>



$('#btn').click(function(){
    if ( $('#div1 input:radio:checked').size() == 3 )    
        return true;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Validate the form when the user submits it, using this validation code.

```
var blank = false;
$("input:radio").each(function() {
    var val = $('input:radio[name=' + this.name + ']:checked').val();
    if (val === undefined) {
        blank = true;
        return false;
    }
});
alert(blank ? "At least one group is blank" : "All groups are checked");
```

First we get the names of all the radio button groups, then check that each one has a value. (Actually we're doing multiple checks, but that doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function check(){
    var allCheck = true;
    if($("#div1 :radio:checked").length==0){
        allCheck=false;
    }
    $("#div1 :radio").each(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<$("#div1 :radio:checked").length;i++)
    if($(this).attr("name")===$($("#div1 :radio:checked")[i]).attr("name")) 
                break;
    else if(i==$("#div1 :radio:checked").length-1) 
                allCheck = false;
    });

    return allCheck;
}
```

Comment: first i have to check the radio group...and second check the checked radio in these group or not...ugly code....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('input:radio', $('#div1')).each(function() {
    if(name && name == $(this).attr('name'))
        return true; // Skip when checking the same element name. 

    name = $(this).attr('name');

    if(! $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length) {
        alert('Oops, you missed some input there.. [' + name + ']');
        return false;
    }
});
```

It will loop through every radio button to check for checked radio & will break as soon it found non-checked radio group (first error found). But if you prefer to get all the errors (not only the first error found), just remove `return false`.

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
if($("#div1").children("input:radio:checked").size() == 3) 
{
   alert('three inputs were checked'); 
}
```